# how to refresh the DOM (and have the right URL after beeing on another page) Jquery-mobile

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-mobile

Good day, I'm learning Jquery mobile and I'm stuck with a simple thing, that maybe should be solved in a minute.

I have made a simple 2 page site, all windows are single HTML PAGES, so I have index.php, contacts.php and sendmail.php (which is only for mailing purposes).

I navigate from index to contacts smoothly, then I fill the form and click submit, the sendmail.php has a `header:('location:')` that redirect the user to index.php after sending the mail, but when I get back to index.php, the navbar is pointing "sendmail.php" which is not right.
is there a way to easy change it (maybe reload a page)?
the form action is like this:

```
<form action="sendmail.php" method="POST">
```

links from page to another are like:
first page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $( function() {   

  $('body').bind( 'swipe', function( e ) {
    $.mobile.changePage( "contatti.php", {      
       transition: "slide", 
       reverse: true, 
       changeHash: false,
       reloadPage: true      
   });
  } ); 


} );


 </script>

<a data-role="button" data-transition="flip" href="contatti.php" data-icon="info"
        data-iconpos="left" class="ui-btn-right" data-prefetch="true">
            Info
        </a>
```

and then the action as described, when i get back to the first page, i have the url like this:

```
/mobile/#/mobile/sendmail.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always modify `window.location.hash = '';`